# bootstrap grid acting weird

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

so i see bootstrap have some weird problem with grid, i don't know is this is bootstrap bug or i doing something wrong, please take a look at this
[image]

so there is some weird gap between those grid and here is my setup/code at first i think it is because different size of image that making it having different height for each column, but hey right now it have the same image with the same image size and still showing problem here....

```
<div class="row">
@foreach($artikels as $artikel)
    <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            @if(!empty($artikel->gambar) && is_file($imagepath.$artikel->gambar."n.jpg"))
                <a class="lightbox" title="{{ $artikel->judul }}" href="{{ asset($imagepath.$artikel->gambar.".jpg") }}">
                    <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></div>
                    {{ HTML::image($imagepath.$artikel->gambar.'n.jpg',$artikel->judul,
                        array('class' => 'img-responsive ')) }}
                </a>
            @else
                <a class="lightbox" title="{{ $artikel->judul }}" href="{{ asset('images/image-article.jpg') }}">
                    <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></div>
                    {{ HTML::image('images/image-articlen.jpg', $artikel->judul, array(
                        'class' => 'img-responsive')) }}
                </a>
            @endif
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="left-meta-post">
            <?php $date = new Date($artikel->created_at); ?>
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">{{ $date->format('j') }}</span><span class="month">{{ $date->format('M') }}</span></div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-title"><a href="{{ route('artikel_detail',array($artikel->id)) }}">{{ $artikel->judul}}</a></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
            <p>
                <a href="{{ route('artikel_detail',array($artikel->id)) }}" style="color:#666;">
                    {{ str_limit(preg_replace('/(<.*?>)|(&.*?;)/', '', $artikel->content),100) }}
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach 
</div>
```

well the code up there is basicly making `<row>` and then put `col-md-4` class into `<div>` inside `<row>`, and each `col-md-4` are warpped with `@foreach` for doing some looping from my database, it just showing all article

note:

i'm using margo version 1.2 from graygrids as bootstrap template but hey i ever using other template even the pure bootstrap version and experienced this, in the past i'm using php to add `<row>` for each 3 item/ article shown and it will solve this issue on destop view/my current view, but when i switch to tablet it become nightmare and i just realize that now

edit:
here is working example/real site [my site](http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel/0) (please note that it maybe not have exactly same item since the screenshot is taken from my local website but the problem stil there)

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML (along with any CSS) as well so there's a working example that demonstrates the issue. [mcve]

Comment: okay already add working site / example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your post blocks each have a different height you need to clear the float that's applied. Since you're using a `col-4-md` you'll want to clear every 3rd post.

```
.portfolio-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

**On a sidenote, you should also take a look at this CSS Rule `.post-content p` inside of `style.css`(you won't see this in my example because only a small part of your CSS is applied to it). One possible solution is to increase the margin from 15px to 50px so your posts stack accordingly on viewports between 992 and 480px. There's multiple solutions for something like this as its just an FYI.

See working Snippet.

```css
/*ADDED CSS RULE*/

.portfolio-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
/*ADDED CSS RULE*/

.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-border {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f8f8f8;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay i {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -27px;
  margin-top: -19px;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-thumb .thumb-overlay i {
  top: 50%;
  color: #444;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details {
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px 12px 6px 12px;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link i,
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link span {
  color: #666;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link:hover i,
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link:hover span {
  color: #F54B5C;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details .like-link i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details h4 {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details a span {
  color: #666;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details span:after {
  content: ", ";
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-details span:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.campaign {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.campaign img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text-center {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
#portfolio-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
#portfolio-list li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#portfolio-list li h3 {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: none;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="row latest-posts-classic">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form method="GET" action="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/cari" accept-charset="UTF-8">

            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan kata kunci" name="q" type="text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="hr1 margin-top"></div>
        <div class="hr1 margin-top"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Happy 27th Anniversary Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/EWO0TuVXsK2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/EWO0TuVXsK2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Happy 27th Anniversary Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">27</span><span class="month">Nov</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/44">Happy 27th Anniversary Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/44" style="color:#666;">
Selamat Ulang Tahun ke 27 Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Inilah Roadmap Credit Union Kalimantan" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/32APzrnupX2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/32APzrnupX2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Inilah Roadmap Credit Union Kalimantan">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">22</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/43">Inilah Roadmap Credit Union Kalimantan</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/43" style="color:#666;">
Sebanyak 44 credit union di bawah kordinasi Pusat Koperasi Kredit BKCU Kalimantan bertekad menja...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>






        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Persiapan Pensiun Sejak Dini" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images/image-article.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images/image-articlen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Persiapan Pensiun Sejak Dini">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">14</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/42">Persiapan Pensiun Sejak Dini</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/42" style="color:#666;">
Uang bukanlah segala-galanya, tapi segala-galanya perlu uang. Kalimat ini bukanlah hal baru bagi kit...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Pemberdayaan dalam Komunitas" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/gRpM7OFOKG2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/gRpM7OFOKG2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Pemberdayaan dalam Komunitas">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">14</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/41">Pemberdayaan dalam Komunitas</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/41" style="color:#666;">
Sejarah Credit Union senyatanya bertumbuh dalam komunitas, dimana anggota saling kenal, percaya, dan...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Penguatan Ekonomi Mikro" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/RdjIDY5XSA2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/RdjIDY5XSA2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Penguatan Ekonomi Mikro">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">14</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/40">Penguatan Ekonomi Mikro</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/40" style="color:#666;">
Sak niki kulo sampun lego, sampun uwal saking abang-abang. Mantun nderek niki , Mpun pokoe entheng l...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Menurunkan Persentase Kelalaian, Pasti bisa." href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/RMKVgScXZX2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/RMKVgScXZX2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Menurunkan Persentase Kelalaian, Pasti bisa.">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">14</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/39">Menurunkan Persentase Kelalaian, Pasti bisa.</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/39" style="color:#666;">
Kredit Lalai sering kita jumpai dan kita dengar di kehidupan sehari-hari, baik dalam skala yang keci...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Happy International Credit Union Day" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/OL9hAD1m6S2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/OL9hAD1m6S2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Happy International Credit Union Day">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">13</span><span class="month">Okt</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/38">Happy International Credit Union Day</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/38" style="color:#666;">
Pengurus , Pengawas Dan Manajemen Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan Mengucapkan Selamat Hari Credit Union In...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="STRATEGI UNTUK PENGEMBANGAN ORGANISASI (ORGANIZATIONA DEVELOPMENT / OD)" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images/image-article.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images/image-articlen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="STRATEGI UNTUK PENGEMBANGAN ORGANISASI (ORGANIZATIONA DEVELOPMENT / OD)">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">16</span><span class="month">Apr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/35">STRATEGI UNTUK PENGEMBANGAN ORGANISASI (ORGANIZATIONA DEVELOPMENT / OD)</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/35" style="color:#666;">
Strategi untuk pengembangan organisasi (Organizational Development/ OD) mengenai perencanaan dan pen...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="20 Tahun Bintang Laut Menerangi Warga Siantan" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/zyHRypJWxt2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/zyHRypJWxt2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="20 Tahun Bintang Laut Menerangi Warga Siantan">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">25</span><span class="month">Feb</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/34">20 Tahun Bintang Laut Menerangi Warga Siantan</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/34" style="color:#666;">
Suatu sore datang seorang ibu ke pastoran Stella Maris. Ia bercerita kepada Pastor Paskalis Soedirdj...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="DEVELOPMENT EDUCATORS : Integrasi Dari Tujuan Pembangunan Sosial dan Jaringan Credit Union" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/Cd0shapwXj2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/Cd0shapwXj2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="DEVELOPMENT EDUCATORS : Integrasi Dari Tujuan Pembangunan Sosial dan Jaringan Credit Union">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">6</span><span class="month">Feb</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/33">DEVELOPMENT EDUCATORS : Integrasi Dari Tujuan Pembangunan Sosial dan Jaringan Credit Union</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/33" style="color:#666;">
Oleh : Serapina Serapin dan Erowin
Mengutip perkataan Diana Ross yang berkata,
Perjalanank...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="Character Building" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/hc2Sq1x6Y02016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/hc2Sq1x6Y02016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="Character Building">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">28</span><span class="month">Jan</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/32">Character Building</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/32" style="color:#666;">
CHARACTER BUILDING
Mengapa Pelatihan Character Building itu penting? - Perjalanan dan pengalaman...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 post-row portfolio-item">
          <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <a class="lightbox" title="BKCU Kalimantan mengadakan Lokakarya Community Development" href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/y1N6JRsvEb2016-01-01.jpg">
              <div class="thumb-overlay"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <img src="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/images_artikel/y1N6JRsvEb2016-01-01n.jpg" class="img-responsive " alt="BKCU Kalimantan mengadakan Lokakarya Community Development">
            </a>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="left-meta-post">
            <div class="post-date"><span class="day">17</span><span class="month">Jan</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-type"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="post-title"><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/31">BKCU Kalimantan mengadakan Lokakarya Community Development</a></h3>
          <div class="post-content">
            <p>
              <a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel_detail/31" style="color:#666;">
Apakah Credit Union anda sudah menjadi Credit Union Sejati?
Pertanyaan yang cukup menyentil...
</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pagination-wrapper">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><span>1</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel/0?page=2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel/0?page=3">3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://puskopditbkcukalimantan.org/artikel/0?page=2" rel="next">&raquo;</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thank you for detailed answer, so when i use col-md i need to clear it out right? and it is applied to all boostrap grid ? or it is just applied to this site only?... oh and yeah i forgot to mention in mobile view it just not stack beautifully..

Comment: My answer is specific to your question, in general how you go about clearing floats will depend on how you configure the grid. In the example its only applied to .portfolio-item class and since you are only using one column size you only have to worry about that column in this instance.

Comment: so can you tell me about basic logic working with this kind of grid? since i have other website that also have this kind of setup... at first i thought that bootstrap will take care of all this problem